# concatAll emits multiple observables and is not subscribing to them

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to get a list of courses from one API endpoint and get the assignments associated with each course from another. I am using concatMap to merge the observables but it isn't working as I expected. Instead of emitting the assignments for each course, it's emitting observable objects.

```
function getCourses() {
  return fromFetch("https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization:
        "Bearer 2~WSiTptufbMw24WKz0gWbb34tSabWEbKKVR5bQY3NEL2b5pd7Ah8OEzM8P64FS4ta",
    },
    selector: responseAsJson,
  });
}

function getAssignments(id: number) {
  return fromFetch(
    `https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/${id}/assignments?bucket=upcoming`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "Bearer ***",
      },
      selector: responseAsJson,
    }
  );
}

const assignments = getCourses()
  .pipe(
    map((response) => response.map((r: any) => getAssignments(r.id))),
    concatAll(),
)
  
assignments.pipe(tap(r => console.log(r))).subscribe();
/*
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
*/
```

Comment: Hi, you asked a question about an hr ago, titled `Generic typescript function expects 3 when only 2 are defined`  here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69623382/generic-typescript-function-expects-3-when-only-2-are-defined   Is there any reason you deleted, as I was about to answer, but obviously can't while it's deleted..

Comment: See https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/238293/re-question-69623382-and-why-i-deleted-it?tab=general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `map()` operator returns `Promise[]` which means it return an array of Promises. `concatAll()` takes the array as an observable-like input, iterates its values and emits them as separate emissions. In other words, `concatAll()` will "subscribe" to the array and not Observables inside the array.

So you need to flatten the array into individual emission for example with `mergeMap()`:

```
const assignments = getCourses()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((response) => response.map((r: any) => getAssignments(r.id))),
    concatAll(),
)
```

... or you could also use two `cocantAll()` but that will look really weird:

```
const assignments = getCourses()
  .pipe(
    map((response) => response.map((r: any) => getAssignments(r.id))),
    concatAll(),
    concatAll(),
)
```

The first `concatAll` will flatten the array and the second one will subscribe to individual Observables.

... or you could just merge all inner Observables

```
const assignments = getCourses()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((response) => merge(...response.map((r: any) => getAssignments(r.id)))),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by using `switchMap` and `forkJoin`

```
const assignments = getCourses().pipe(
  // unsubscribe from the outer observable after the inner emits
  switchMap((response) =>
    // convert a collection of observables into an observable collection
    forkJoin(response.map((r: any) => getAssignments(r.id)))
  )
);
```